# Load fields from line if booleans are checked on wizard - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this wizard code:

```
class generate_print_order(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'generate.print.order'

    isbns = fields.One2many('order.lines', 'order_id', 'ISBN')
    production_order = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', 'Production Order')

@api.model
def default_get(self, fields):
    res = super(generate_print_order, self).default_get(fields)
    isbns = []
    if self.env.context.has_key('active_id'):
        production_order = self.env.context['active_id']
        order = self.env['bsi.production.order'].browse(production_order)
        for line in order.order_lines:
            if line.remaining_qty > 0:
                val = {
                    'name': 'name',
                    'isbn':line.isbn.id,
                    'qty': line.remaining_qty}
                isbns.append([0,0,val])
        res.update({'isbns':isbns,'production_order':production_order})
    return res

@api.multi    
def generate(self):
    if self.isbns:
        order_lines = []
        print_order = self.env['bsi.print.order'].create({
            'state': 'draft',
            'production_orders':self.production_order.id,
            })
        for line in self.isbns:
            order_lines.append(self.env['bsi.print.order.lines'].create({
                'print_order':print_order.id,
                'isbn':line.isbn.id,
                'qty':line.qty}))
            prod_isbn = self.env['bsi.production.order.lines'].search([('production_order','=',self.production_order.id),
                                                           ('isbn','=',line.isbn.id)])
            prod_isbn.consumed_qty = line.qty
        print_order.write({'order_lines':[(6,0,map(lambda x:x.id,order_lines))]})
        tree_view_id = self.env.ref('bsi.bsi_print_orders_view_tree').id
        form_view_id = self.env.ref('bsi.view_print_order_form').id
        self.production_order.state = 'print_order_inprogress'
        return {
            'name': _('Print Order'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'bsi.print.order',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'views': [(tree_view_id, 'tree'),(form_view_id, 'form')],
            'view_id':tree_view_id,
            'res_id': [print_order.id],
            'domain': [('id', 'in', [print_order.id])]
             }

class order_lines(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'order.lines'

    order_id = fields.Many2one('generate.print.order', 'Order')
    isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
    qty = fields.Float(string="Quantity")
```

This is the `bsi.print.order.line` model:

```
class bsi_print_order_lines(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.print.order.lines'

    print_order = fields.Many2one('bsi.print.order', string="Print Order")
    isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
    qty = fields.Integer(string="Quantity")
    consumed_qty = fields.Integer(string="Quantity consumed")
    remaining_qty = fields.Float(string="Remaining quantity") #, compute="_remaining_func"
    is_book_block = fields.Boolean(string="Is Book Block Done")
    is_binding = fields.Boolean(string="Is Binding Done")
    is_edging = fields.Boolean(string="Is Edging Done")
    isbns = fields.Many2one('worksheets.isbns', string="Worksheet ISBNS")
```

What I'm confused at, is how can I launch this wizard only if `is_book_block, is_binding and is_edging` are all three on `True` state.

Should I declare those fields as I did with `order.lines` on `TransientModel`?

Like this:

```
class order_lines(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'order.lines'

    order_id = fields.Many2one('generate.print.order', 'Order')
    isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
    qty = fields.Float(string="Quantity")
    is_binding = fields.Boolean(string="Is Binding Done", default=True)
    is_edging = fields.Boolean(string="Is Edging Done", default=True)
    is_book_block = fields.Boolean(string="Is Book Block Done", default=True)
```

But I'm not sure on how to achieve it

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that in odoo is using a button to open the wizard but 
i'm a little bit confuesed here the field that you condition are in the order line 
not the order so when you say you want to open this wizard if this field are all true
what do you mean exactly :

```
  1 - if there is only one line that all the three field are true, you can open the wizard
  2 - all the line in the order must have this three field then you can open the wizard.
```

for bouth cases you can do some thing like that :

```
 1 - create a boolean field in the order witch is compute field 
 2 - compute the value of the field based on condition 1 or 2
 3 - add a button the the form of the order and show it only if the field is true.
 4- don't forget to add this field too to the form so you can use it in attrs   
 5- in order define a method to open the wizard and pass the same context to wizard (active_id)
```

in order form :

```xml
<field name="new_field" invisible="1"/>
<button name="open_wizard" type="object" 
           class="oe_highlight"
           attrs="{'readonly':[('new_field','=',True)]}"
           />
```

in oreder:

```py
# note change the name of the method so you can understand you code next time ^^
@api.multi
def open_wizard(self):
    """ open wizard for ....  """
    return {
        # pass the same context to access active_id 
        'context': self.env.context,        
        'name': 'Your title Here',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'generate.print.order',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    }
```

and for the field:

```py
new_field = fields.Boolean('check ...' , compute='check_fields', store=True)

depends('line_ids', 
    'line_ids.is_binding',
    'line_ids.is_edging',
    'line_ids.is_book_block',)
def check_fields(self):
    """ check fields"""
    for rec in self:
        if any( line.is_binding and line.is_edging and line.is_book_block               for line in rec.order_lines):
            rec.new_field = True

        else:
            rec.new_field = False
```

Comment: You are my hero, lol, I'm surely learning a lot with You :) thank You very much